# how to solve requirejs permit error

Tags: node.js, requirejs

OS: Win7 x86

```
node r.js -o app.build.js
```

It returns this error

```
Error: Error: EPERM, operation not permitted 
'D:\work\interactBack\src\main\webapp\back\javascripts\.svn\all-wcprops'
      at Object.fs.unlinkSync (fs.js:760:18)
```

Then I tried to run cmd with administrator type, it still didn't work

Answer (score 1):

This error occured to me when the file/folder reported in the error is read-only, making it writable solved the issue to me.